# How is the PR of the car calculated in NFS No Limits?

Tags: need-for-speed-no-limits

I have a few cars, and parts are rare to come by, so I need to  look for the place to fit them for the maximum increase in PR, so that the car is allowed for more races. So my question is, how does an increase in top speed, acceleration, and nitro affect the increase in PR?